# How to add Class or ID to Overlay in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I add a class or ID to an Overlay in the Google Maps API? Example:

```js
subOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.addClass="map_marker";   // I try
    this.div_ = div;
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
}
```

But not working :( Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You have got the wrong property. It's [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className), not `addClass`:

```
div.className = "map_marker";
```

You may have been thinking of the jQuery method, `addClass`, in which case you would need to call the method, rather than assigning to it.